# ActiveX component can't create object: 'CDONTS.Newmail'

Tags: asp-classic, cdonts

I'm getting this error on a windows 2003 server:

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01ad'

ActiveX component can't create object: 'CDONTS.Newmail'

I really don't want to have to change the code to something else.  is there some way i can get CDONTS to work onw indows 2003.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and run CDONTS on Windows 2003 - you'll need to download the DLL (try http://www.thevbzone.com/d_DLL.htm) and then install it by running:

```
C:\Inetpub\WebDlls>regsvr32 cdonts.dll
```

Then do an iisreset and you should find your scripts can create CDONTS.NewMail as they could on Windows NT and 2000.

Comment: iisreset should not be necessary. You should be able to use any com object as soon as it's been regsvr32'd.